# Randomly selecting (units) from a file where a unit is 2 lines.

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, text-processing

I want to select from a file random lines/units but where the units are consisted of 2 lines.

For example a file looks like this

> Adam
>   Apple
>   Mindy
>   Candy
>   Steve
>   Chips
>   David
>   Meat
>   Carol
>   Carrots

And I want to randomly subselect lets say 2 units group

For example

> Adam
>   Apple
>   David
>   Meat

or

> Steve
>   Chips
>   Carol
>   Carrots

I've tried using `shuf` and `sort -R` but they only shuffle 1 lines. Could someone help me please? 
Thank you.

Comment: How many units do you want to be able to select?

Comment: Is it acceptable to select the 2nd and 3rd lines?

Comment: Have you considered preprocessing the data so that you only need to select single lines at random, and then reformat the selected lines as two lines each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with `shuf` by joining the lines before shuffling (that might not be a bad idea for a file format in general, if the lines describe a single item):

```
$ < file sed -e 'N;s/\n/:/' | shuf | head -1 | tr ':' '\n'
Carol
Carrots
```

The `sed` loads two lines at a time, and joins them with a colon.

Comment: You don't need the p, just remove the -n flag. Also if your sed supports `\n` then you don't need the -e either and it accepts filenames as arg so you don't need `<`. It could be written as   `sed 'N;s/\n/:/' file`

Answer (score 0):

Pick a random number in the correct range, ensure that it is odd (if desired), then use `sed` to print the 2 lines:

```
$ a=$(expr $RANDOM % \( $(wc -l < input) / 2 \) \* 2 + 1)
$ sed -n -e ${a}p -e $((a+1))p input
```

Comment: Any reason you chose `expr` over `$(())` or `(())`?

Comment: No.  It was just the first thing I typed.  Any reasonable person would use `a=$(( $RANDOM % ( $( wc -l < input ) / 2 ) * 2 + 1))`

Comment: Well, any reasonable person would probably do something else entirely :)  But this works.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than selecting lines to print, you could walk the file and print each "unit" with a particular probability.  For example, to print (roughly) 10% of the "units" in the file, you could do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand()} NR%2 && (rand() < .1) {print; getline; print}' input
```

Comment: This prints nothing for me 90% of the time.